# 3d graph with contours lines

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, 3d

How add the contours under the graph using the R as in plot 2?
I've searched a lot on the internet and found no example of how to do it in R! Is there any function or package to add the outline along with the chart?

```
#Function density probability
library(pbivnorm)
bsb <- function(t1,t2){
a1 <- sqrt(phi1/2)*(sqrt(((phi1+1)*t1)/(phi1*mu1))-sqrt(((phi1*mu1)/((phi1+1)*t1))))
  a2 <- sqrt(phi2/2)*(sqrt(((phi2+1)*t2)/(phi2*mu2))-sqrt(((phi2*mu2)/((phi2+1)*t2))))
  Phi2 <- pbivnorm(a1, a2, rho, recycle = TRUE)
  b1 <- ((phi1+1)/(2*phi1*mu1))*sqrt(phi1/2)*(((phi1*mu1)/((phi1+1)*t1))^(1/2)+((phi1*mu1)/((phi1+1)*t1))^(3/2))
  b2 <- ((phi2+1)/(2*phi2*mu2))*sqrt(phi2/2)*(((phi2*mu2)/((phi2+1)*t2))^(1/2)+((phi2*mu2)/((phi2+1)*t2))^(3/2))
  fdp <- Phi2*b1*b2
  return(fdp)
}
t1 <- seq(0.001,5,length=100)
t2 <- seq(0.001,5,length=100)
#Parameters
mu1=5
phi1=2
mu2=5
phi2=2
rho=0.9

z<-outer(t1,t2,bsb) # calculate density values

persp(t1, t2, z, # 3-D plot
      main="Bivariate Birnbaum-Saunders",
      col="lightgray",
      theta=40, phi=10,
      r=10,
      d=0.9,
      expand=0.5,
      ltheta=90, lphi=80,
      shade=0.9,
      ticktype="detailed",
      nticks=5)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: ggplot2 (the main package, at least) is purely 2d, though its raster and contour functions let it plot similar data. plotly may be a good option for 3d plotting, as it gives users freedom to change the angle, which makes 3d plots more useful.

Comment: @alistaire, without using ggplot2/ploty how can I do to join the above graph with the contours, as the second chart?

Comment: It looks like it might be possible with `trans3d` and the transformation matrix returned by `persp`. At a minimum you could do something with `lines` that way, as the example in `persp` shows.

Comment: @alistaire I've already tried this package! Unfortunately it did not work!

Comment: They're not packages, they're functions from the base R.

Comment: Yes, I wrote it wrong, I mean I already used these functions but I did not make the graph as desire!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved:

```
source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/walmes/wzRfun/master/R/panel.3d.contour.R")
library(lattice)
library(manipulate)
library(colorRamps)

#Function density probability
library(pbivnorm)
bsb <- function(t1,t2){
  a1 <- sqrt(phi1/2)*(sqrt(((phi1+1)*t1)/(phi1*mu1))-sqrt(((phi1*mu1)/((phi1+1)*t1))))
  a2 <- sqrt(phi2/2)*(sqrt(((phi2+1)*t2)/(phi2*mu2))-sqrt(((phi2*mu2)/((phi2+1)*t2))))
  Phi2 <- pbivnorm(a1, a2, rho, recycle = TRUE)
  b1 <- ((phi1+1)/(2*phi1*mu1))*sqrt(phi1/2)*(((phi1*mu1)/((phi1+1)*t1))^(1/2)+((phi1*mu1)/((phi1+1)*t1))^(3/2))
  b2 <- ((phi2+1)/(2*phi2*mu2))*sqrt(phi2/2)*(((phi2*mu2)/((phi2+1)*t2))^(1/2)+((phi2*mu2)/((phi2+1)*t2))^(3/2))
  fdp <- Phi2*b1*b2
  return(fdp)
}
#Parameters
mu1=5
phi1=2
mu2=5
phi2=2
rho=0.9
grid <- expand.grid(t1 = seq(0.001,8, by = 0.1),
                    t2 = seq(0.001,8, by = 0.1))
grid$z <- bsb(grid$t1,grid$t2)

manipulate({
  ## Makes the three-dimensional chart
  colr <- colorRampPalette(c(c1, c2, c3), space="rgb")
  arrows <- arr
  wireframe(z ~ t1 + t2,
            data = grid,
            scales = list(arrows = FALSE),
            zlim = extendrange(grid$z, f = 0.25),
            panel.3d.wireframe = "panel.3d.contour",
            nlevels = 8,
            col = "gray40",
            type = c("bottom"),
            col.regions = colr(101),
            drape = TRUE, colorkey=FALSE,
            screen=list(z=z.angle, x=x.angle),
            axis.line = list(col = "transparent"),
            clip = list(panel = "off"),
            par.settings = list(box.3d = list(col=c(1,NA,NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA))))
},
## Controls the value of angles and colors
z.angle=slider(0, 360, step=10, initial=40),
x.angle=slider(-180, 0, step=5, initial=-80),
arr=checkbox(FALSE, "show.arrows"),
c1=picker("transparent","black","red","yellow","orange","green","blue","pink","violet"),
c2=picker("transparent","black","red","yellow","orange","green","blue","pink","violet"),
c3=picker("transparent","black","red","yellow","orange","green","blue","pink","violet")
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As @alistaire pointed out, it actually requires a single line to get the plotly version, see for documentation to edit details of the plot (https://plot.ly/r/3d-surface-plots/)

```
test<-outer(t1,t2,bsb) # your output matrix
p <- plot_ly(z = ~test) %>% add_surface()
p
```